Azure Data Factory (ADF) fails to pick up Global Parameters after publishing
I specified some Global Parameters in my ADF instance.
While debugging everything works as expected or in other words the activities can pick up the values specified in Global Params
After publishing though, I get this error message:
Operation on target xxxx failed: The expression 'pipeline().globalParameters.zzzzz' 
cannot be evaluated because property 'zzzzz' doesn't exist, available properties are ''. 

I publish /deploy using an Azure DevOps pipeline which looks like:
- task: SQLPlayer.DataFactoryTools.PublishADF.PublishADFTask@2
            displayName: 'blablabla'
            inputs:
              .
              .
              .
              FilterText: |
                +pipeline.*
                .
                .
                .
                +globalParameters.*  <- I tried this just in case but not progress (I dont even know if this is valid)

I tried these solutions but they didn't work out for me

I tried to delete the global Param -< recreate it -> Publish again but I get the same error message. [link][1]

I tried to update In your publish_config.json with includeGlobalParamsTemplate [link][2]


{"publishBranch": "adf_publish", "includeGlobalParamsTemplate": true}

[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/97868/adf-global-parameters-error-after-trigger-(debug-w
[2]: Azure Data Factory global parameters don't work with new deployment method
